# How are the last non-zero digits of $(10^9)!$ computed?

Tags: factorial, computational-mathematics, big-numbers

Plugging in $(10^9)!$ in WolframAlpha gives a result of $...3160933638144$.I have an idea to how to calculate the last non-zero digit with modular arithmetics but how does WA compute the last 13 non-zero digits?

Comment: Drip algoritms come to mind

Comment: Also something is wrong there, the last digits should be 0's

Comment: the last $\mathbf{non-zero}$ digits

Comment: Ah missed that, well drip algorithm is my guess still

Comment: Use your modular algorithm, but factor out powers of $10$ rather than multiply them in. (take care that you often need to factor out a $5$ and a previous $2$ separately)

Comment: You can even cheat here; you know the last 13 digits are surely going to be a multiple of $2^{13}$, so you only need to compute the result modulo $5^{13}$ (but removing the factors of $5$ rather than multiplying them in)

Comment: @ZelosMalum: A link would be nice $-$ googling "drip algorithm" comes up with page after page of medical dosage articles.

Comment: @solonasus why did u delete your answer?  I was going to +1 it and got rejected :-( .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to this question after googling a bit. It is actually pretty simple.

> when multiplying integers, any  digit past the last 2 will not effect the last >2.
>
> For instance, take 8!
>   8*7 = 56
>   56*6 = 336 = 36
>   36*5=180 = 80
>   80*4 = 320 = 20
>   20*3 = 60 
>   60*2 = 120 = 20

Now we can use the same method for any number of last digits we want to find. The only thing we need to take care is to remove the zeroes.

I wrote this function in C++ that finds the last 12 non-zero digits of a factorial `p`. It works for `p`<1,000,000.

```
    long long temp=1;
    int i=1;
    long long factorial_digits(int p)
    {
    do
    {
    temp=temp*i;
    while(temp%10==0)
            temp=temp/10;
    temp=temp%1000000000000;
    i++;
    }

    while(i<=p);
        return temp;
    }
```